Unable to Receive Invite for Test User to Access Meta Page
We are trying to get page_messaging and page_manage_metadata permissions for our app to automatically reply to users when they message us. However, the Meta reviewer requires a test account with access to the page to verify this functionality. To enable this, we need to invite the test user to access the page.
We've created the test account and sent an invite to the test user and logged in as the test user, but we are not receiving any invitations. Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone know how to resolve it?

AFAIK, actual test users created from within the app dashboard, can not interact with real pages. Only real Facebook user accounts that have been added as an admin/developer/tester can. (A real account added as "tester", is something different than a "test user".)
